# I have an error in my hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: java, hibernate, crud

This is the cfg file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property
      name="hibernate.connection.password">Chitaramea2198</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">50</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping resource="src/Main/Employee.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

The error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingNotFoundException: 
>   resource: src/Main/Employee.hbm.xml not found

My project structure:

[image: project structure]

Does anybody know how could I fix this error? I tried different 
  paths for the hbm xml file , i even tried to move it same place 
  with the cfg file but it still doesnt work, I am a newbie and dont 
  really know much about it, I tried to follow some tutorials but I 
  still cannot manage to make it work. 
Thank you!

This is the project:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8d00be7b4a302b7cca39c87a6bc42f4a20200125220719/309934c0d43ae5bb15201ba3850ba14b20200125220719/01da4d

Comment: Do not add content from WeTransfer. What should it be?

Comment: If you want to add code, add it to the question, please. Separate relevant class in a block code for each one.

Comment: @VictorAndrei Try `Main/Employee.hbm.xml` instead of `src/Main/Employee.hbm.xml`.